gsap scrolltrigger for horizontal content
I'm really struggling with gsap.
Im trying to have room-top__flex content to scroll horizontally when room-top is pinned.
It's working but my issue is that i would like it to be unpinned when the last gsap-room is fully seen (so we still see some part of the second one) but right now its been unpinned when the last gsap-room is on the left of the screen so there is a blank space on the right.
Is there a way ? i dont mind the last gsap-room expanding to take the full width.
here is the code so far :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>GSAP Horizontal Scroll</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      font-family: "FP-ヒラギノ角ゴ ProN W3", sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 300;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
      line-height: 2.5;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      line-break: strict;
    }

    #wrapper {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .main {
      display: block;
      padding-top: 0;
    }

    .block {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: green;
    }
    .room-tp {
      background: pink;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .room-tp .top-title {
      padding-top: 65px;
      font-size: 90px;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .room-tp__flex {
      display: flex;
      width: max-content;
    }

    .room-top__img {
      width: 80vw;
      height: calc(100vh - 160px);
    }

    .room-top__img img {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .room-tp__container {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .big-space {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: red;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .blue {
      background-color: teal;
    }

    .gsap-about-flex {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200");
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .gsap-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .text-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .text-container h2, .text-container p {
      color: white;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }

    .gsap-about-before {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: white;
    }

    .gsap-about-after {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: white;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <main class="main">
      <div class="block"></div>

      <div class="gsap-container">
        <div class="gsap-about-flex">
          <div class="gsap-about-before"></div>
          <div class="gsap-about-after"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-container">
          <h2>Hello</h2>
          <p>this is some text</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <section class="room-tp">
        <h2 class="top-title top-title--right">ROOM</h2>

        <div class="room-tp__wrapper">
          <div class="room-tp__flex">
            <div class="gsap-room">
              <a href="/room/#room401" class="room-tp__container">
                <div class="room-top__img">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/19/200/300" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="room-top__info">
                  <p class="room-top__list">meeting</p>
                  <p class="room-top__info-title">401</p>
                  <a href="/room/#room401" class="room-top__button">VIEW MORE <i class="ico-arrow"></i></a>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="gsap-room">
              <a href="/room/#room402" class="room-tp__container">
                <div class="room-top__img">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/20/200/300" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="room-top__info">
                  <p class="room-top__list">meeting</p>
                  <p class="room-top__info-title">¥402</p>
                  <a href="/room/#room402" class="room-top__button">VIEW MORE <i class="ico-arrow"></i></a>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="gsap-room">
              <a href="/room/#room501" class="room-tp__container">
                <div class="room-top__img">
                  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/200/300" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="room-top__info">
                  <p class="room-top__list">offline</p>
                  <p class="room-top__info-title">501</p>
                  <a href="/room/#room501" class="room-top__button">VIEW MORE <i class="ico-arrow"></i></a>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    gsap.to(".gsap-about-before", {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".gsap-container",
        start: "top top",
        end: "+=100%",
        scrub: true,
        pin: true,
        toggleActions: "play none none reverse"
      },
      x: '-100%',
      duration: 3
    });

    gsap.to(".gsap-about-after", {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".gsap-container",
        start: "top top",
        end: "+=100%",
        scrub: true,
        pin: false,
        toggleActions: "play none none reverse"
      },
      x: '100%',
      duration: 3
    });

    let sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".gsap-room");

    // Calculate the width to stop scrolling when half of the second gsap-room is visible
    const stopWidth = document.querySelector(".gsap-room").offsetWidth * 1.5;

    gsap.to(sections, {
      xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".room-tp",
        pin: true,
        scrub: true,
        snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
        end: () => "+=" + (stopWidth - window.innerWidth),
        markers: true,
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>



You can try something like this
 gsap.to(sections, {
      xPercent: -90 * (sections.length - 1),
      ease: "none",
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".room-tp",
        pin: true,
        scrub: true,
        snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
        end: () => "+=" + (stopWidth - window.innerWidth),
        markers: true,
      }
    });

.room-top__img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 160px);
}
.room-tp__flex:first-child{
    transform: translateX( -20vw);
}
.gsap-room:first-child .room-top__img{
    width: 100vw;
    padding-left: 20vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

